# Set <ApplicationDisplayVersion> using Target BeforeBuild in csproj

Tags: maui, .net-maui

Before project builds, I would like to read from external source and set the `<ApplicationDisplayVersion>`. In my csproj, I've the following:

```xml
...
<Target Name="CalculateVersionCodeProperties" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">         
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.2.3</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>2</ApplicationVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
...
```

But the above doesn't seems to work. When running `AppInfo.VersionString` in the code, it is showing the default `1.0.0`.

Is there a way to set `<ApplicationDisplayVersion>` using MSBuild `<Target>`?

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code first:

```
<ApplicationVersion Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('android'))">(BuildNumber)</ApplicationVersion>
<ApplicationVersion Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('ios'))">(BuildNumber)</ApplicationVersion>
```

more information : https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1662

Comment: nope. Not working. And the github issue reference is not quite relevant to my question